# How to add each JSON row into a global jQuery variable?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I have a following jQuery code

The function is, I run it to retrieve 10 row each time from the database via AJAX call.

When the data is received back on AJAX callback, each row of the response is appended to a global array.

Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var oTable;
var outer_start_row = 0;
var outer_limit = 10;
var final_data = []; 
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.prettyPrint() && prettyPrint();
    $('#load').click(function()
    {
        load_data_in_datatable();
    });
});

function load_data_in_datatable()
{

        var v = $('#drp_v').val();
        var cnt = $('#drp_cnt').val();
        var ctg = $('#drp_ctg').val();
        var api = $('#drp_api').val();
        var nt = $('#drp_nt').val();
        alert('outside start_row :'+outer_start_row);
        $.post("ajax.php",
            {   'version':v,'category':ctg,
                'country':cnt,'network_id':nt,
                'api':api,'func':'show_datatable',
                'start_row':outer_start_row,'limit':outer_limit},
                        function(response)
                        {
                            var data = response.data;
                            var limits = response.limits;
                            outer_limit = limits.limit;
                            outer_start_row = limits.start_row;
                            alert('inside start_row :'+outer_start_row);

                            final_data.push(data);

                            for(var f = 0; f < final_data.length; f++) 
                                alert(final_data[f].name);
                            load_data_in_datatable();
                        },'json');

}
</script>
```

but the problem is, when i am using this alert(final_data[f].name); its alerting undefined.

Don't know whats going wrong

here's my php ajax function

```
function show_datatable($version,$ctg,$cnt,$nt,$api,$start_row,$limit)
{

    $cnt_table = "aw_countries_".$version;
    $ctg_table = "aw_categories_".$version;
    $off_table = "aw_offers_".$version;
    $sizeof_ctg = count($ctg);
    $cond_ctg = " ( ";
    for($c = 0; $c < $sizeof_ctg ; $c++)
    {
        $cond_ctg = $cond_ctg." $ctg_table.category = '".$ctg[$c]."' ";
        if($c < intval($sizeof_ctg-1))
            $cond_ctg = $cond_ctg." OR ";
        else if($c == intval($sizeof_ctg-1))
            $cond_ctg = $cond_ctg." ) ";
    }
    $sizeof_cnt = count($cnt);
    $cond_cnt = " ( ";
    for($cn = 0; $cn < $sizeof_cnt ; $cn++)
    {
        $cond_cnt = $cond_cnt." $cnt_table.country = '".$cnt[$cn]."' ";
        if($cn < intval($sizeof_cnt-1))
            $cond_cnt = $cond_cnt." OR ";
        else if($cn == intval($sizeof_cnt-1))
            $cond_cnt = $cond_cnt." ) ";
    }
    $sizeof_nt = count($nt);
    $cond_nt = " ( ";
    for($n = 0; $n < $sizeof_nt ; $n++)
    {
        $cond_nt = $cond_nt." $off_table.network_id = '".$nt[$n]."' ";
        if($n < intval($sizeof_nt-1))
            $cond_nt = $cond_nt." OR ";
        else if($n == intval($sizeof_nt-1))
            $cond_nt = $cond_nt." ) ";
    }
    $sizeof_api = count($api);
    $cond_api = " ( ";
    for($a = 0; $a < $sizeof_api ; $a++)
    {
        $cond_api = $cond_api." $off_table.api_key = '".$api[$a]."' ";
        if($a < intval($sizeof_api-1))
            $cond_api = $cond_api." OR ";
        else if($a == intval($sizeof_api-1))
            $cond_api = $cond_api." ) ";
    }
    $output         = "";
    $sql = "SELECT $off_table.id, $off_table.name
            FROM $off_table,$cnt_table,$ctg_table
            WHERE  $off_table.id = $cnt_table.id
            AND $off_table.id = $ctg_table.id
            AND ".$cond_api."
            AND ".$cond_nt."
            AND ".$cond_cnt."
            AND ".$cond_ctg." LIMIT $start_row , $limit";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $arr_result = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $arr_result[] = $row;
    }
    //$arr_result_enc = json_encode($arr_result);
    //echo $arr_result_enc;



    $arr_limit = array(
            'start_row' => intval($start_row + $limit),
            'limit' => $limit
    );
    //$arr_limit_enc = json_encode($arr_limit);
    //echo $arr_limit_enc;
    $result_json = array(
    'data'   => $arr_result,
    'limits' => $arr_limit,
);

echo json_encode($result_json);
}
```

EDIT:

Here's a JSON format

```
{"data":[{"id":"11105","name":"Gummy Drop (iPhone, Free, ROW except CN, 72.3MB, w"}],"limits":{"start_row":1,"limit":"1"}}
```

Comment: Can you `console.log(data)` to verify what json data you're getting back?

Comment: Can you add what response are you getting from ajax call?(Json code)

Comment: Also note that you're pushing the entire data returned into one array element, rather than individual ones

Answer (score 1):

You can't push the entire data in in one go like this:

```
final_data.push(data);
```

as `data` itself is an array, and arrays don't have a `name` property, which is why you're getting the error you see.  You need to loop through it and push the individual elements:

```
for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++)
    final_data.push(data[x]);
```